# Remote access for MariaDB on RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I need access from a cloud app server to a RDS instance.  @Somethingwhatever solved my problem of access between 2 on-prem servers with this code.  Similar code does not work on AWS RDS.  (I have added security groups to the instance that authorize a specific ip, and seeing if we can get an ip for the app server.)  But would appreciate insight if this approach will work on RDS.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ7ub.png)

Comment: Sorry, but you have not provided enough information to understand what you are wanting to accomplish. Are you saying that you are unable to connect to the Amazon RDS database? Your picture says that there is an error using `CREATE USER` -- does that mean you have successfully connected to the database prior to running this command? Can you create non-admin users? Please Edit your question to provide more information about what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I am able to connect to RDS database from the ip that are in the VPC security group.  Is it possible to create a user that could connect without having the ip be in a security group?  It has been mentioned to make it a public database.  Not sure exactly what that means, or if that is wise .  I currently don't have the ip of the cloud app server that needs to connect, and am waiting on feedback on that.  New to all this, so am searching as I go.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share how your problem is related to programming. If it is not, please move it to superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: Security Groups block traffic at the network level, without knowledge of 'who' is making the request. To better protect your database, it is normally recommended to keep the database in a Private Subnet (which means it has no direct access from the Internet) and to permit access from the applications that will use it. If you want to connect to the database from the Internet, you would first need to connect to a server in the same VPC and from there connect to the database. Alternatively, put it in a Public Subnet and ensure that incoming traffic is limited to specific IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks John.  We do need to access the database from a cloud platform, that happens to be provisioned with AWS resources.  But I know nothing of private subnets, etc.  I did get the 3 ips this platform will use and created an inbound rule, and found I could put all 3 ips in the same rule.  I think we are good to go.